# Parsing string with grep

Tags: linux, parsing, sed, grep

I need some help with parsing a string in Linux.

I have a string:

```
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds
```

and want to get only

```
2 minutes 8 seconds
```

Comment: Have you actually read `man sed`?

Comment: I try with grep but it is wrong

Comment: What makes you think that `grep` is the right tool for this job? Is this a case of "only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the line prefix is always the same, simply use sed and replace the prefix with an empty string:

```
sed 's/\[INFO\] Total Time: //'
```

Assuming that the time is always the last thing in a line after a colon, use the following regex (replace each line with everything after the colon):

```
sed 's/^.*: \(.*\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `grep`:

```
$ echo '[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds' | grep -o '[[:digit:]].*$'
2 minutes 8 seconds
```

Or `sed`:

```
$ echo '[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds' | sed 's/.*: //'
2 minutes 8 seconds
```

Or `awk`:

```
$ echo '[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
2 minutes 8 seconds
```

Or `cut`:

```
$ echo '[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds' | cut -d: -f2
 2 minutes 8 seconds
```

And then read [*sed & awk, Second Edition*](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Sed_awk.html?id=Xu0G31e-4gIC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 7):

The sed and perl options do work, but in this trivial case, I'd prefer

```
 echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | cut -d: -f2
```

If you have something against spaces, you can just use

```
 echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | cut -d: -f2 | xargs
```

or even...

```
 echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -c2-
```

PS. Trivia: you could do this with `grep` only if grep implemented positive lookbehind like this `egrep -o '(?<=: ).*'`; Unfortunately neither POSIX extended regex nor GNU extended regex implement lookbehind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer AWK then it is quite simple

```
echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | awk -F": " '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` or `perl`:

```
echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | sed -e 's/^\[INFO\] Total time:\s*//'
echo "[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 8 seconds" | perl -pe "s/^\[INFO\] Total time:\s*//;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the info from the terminal then you can grep out the info and use cut with the delimiter to remove everything before the info you want.
grep INFO | cut -f2 -d:

If you want the info out of a file then you can grep the file
grep INFO somefilename | cut -f2 -d: