# how to use .replace with match() method javaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, match

i need to replace some data obtained from match();

This one return string that contain "Total time: 9 minutes 24 seconds"

```
data.match(/Total time: [0-9]* minutes [0-9]* seconds/);
```

but i need only "9 minutes 24 seconds", I try use:

```
data.match(/Total time: [0-9]* minutes [0-9]* seconds/).replace("Total time:", "");
```

but there is an error ""

```
".replace is not a function"
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: This looks very similar to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119585/parsing-string-with-grep . What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Roman, do you need any further help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = 'Total time: 15 minutes 30 seconds';
response = data.match(/Total time: [0-9]* minutes [0-9]* seconds/);
response = response[0];
alert(response.replace("Total time:", ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use capturing sub expressions in your regex:

```
var match = data.match(/Total time: ([0-9]* minutes [0-9]* seconds)/);
alert(match[1]);
```

`match()` returns an array, which is why you can't call `replace` on the result — there is no `Array#replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of using match doing something like this...

```
var match = data.replace(/Total time: ([0-9]* minutes [0-9]* seconds)/,"$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will return an array of matches or null if no match is found.  The original code attempts to call the `replace` method on an instance of an Array instead of the element (a String) within it.

```
var result = null;
var m = data.match(/.../);
if (m) {
  result = m[0].replace('Total time: ', '');
}
```